# Why sqlite table column _id doesn't work

Tags: android, sqlite

I met with one problem: when toying with `SQLite` database & `SimpleCursorAdapter`, I created a table with `_id` primary key column explicitly:

```
public class NoteDbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "notes_db";

private static final String NOTE_TABLE_NAME = "note";
private static final String NOTE_COL_ID = "_id";
private static final String NOTE_COL_TITLE = "title";
private static final String NOTE_COL_CONTENT = "content";
private static final String NOTE_COL_CREATED = "created";
private static final String NOTE_COL_MODIFIED = "modified";

private static final String[] NOTE_COL_PROJECTION = new String[] {
        NOTE_COL_TITLE, NOTE_COL_CONTENT, };

public NoteDbHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

// Create table
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String createNoteTableSql = "CREATE TABLE " + NOTE_TABLE_NAME + " ("
            + NOTE_COL_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + NOTE_COL_TITLE
            + " TEXT," + NOTE_COL_CONTENT + " TEXT," + NOTE_COL_CREATED
            + " INTEGER," + NOTE_COL_MODIFIED + " INTEGER" + ");";
    db.execSQL(createNoteTableSql);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // Drop older table if existed
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + NOTE_TABLE_NAME);

    // Create tables again
    onCreate(db);
}
```

Since `SimpleCursorAdapter` needs a `Cursor' object, so I created function:

```
    public Cursor getAllNotesCursor() {
    String selectQuery = "SELECT _id as _id, title, content FROM " + NOTE_TABLE_NAME;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    return cursor;
}
```

Note that I need to use `SELECT _id as _id` to make things work, `SELECT _id, title...` doesn't work, do you know why?

Comment: you probably want your primary key creation to `autoincrement` every time a new item is added to the database so you need `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,`

Comment: What is your error ? did you modify the columns after having created the table for the first time ? if so, you will just have to upgrade the database version in order to enforce it to be re created

Comment: I uninstall the aplication when you work with sql and have made changes or like @Zoubiock said upgrade the db version